# Timed AJAX request, reload if content is different

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using the following script to check if the content of `currentshow.php` and `#current-show` (on the existing page) are different. If they are different then I want to replace `#current-show` with `currentshow.php`:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

var auto_refresh = setInterval(
    function (){
        function getcurrentshow(){
         var result = null;
         jQuery.ajax({
            url: '/currentshow.php',
            type: 'get',
            dataType: 'html',
            async: false,
            success: function(data) {
                result = data;
            } 
         });
         return result;
        }

        gcs = getcurrentshow();
        cs = jQuery('#current-show').html();
        if (gcs != cs){
            jQuery('#current-show').load('/currentshow.php');
        };
    }, 1000);
)};
```

I do `console.log(gcs)` and `console.log(cs)` and both return exactly the same thing in the JS console. However, the content reloads every second anyway.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Hi, do you mean the #current-show reload every sec?

Comment: Can it possibly be a Whitespace issue?  Eventhough it looks the same, some white space might've slipped in there someway?  I would do `$.trim(getcurrentshow())` & `$.trim(jQuery('#current-show').html())`.  Just in case.  Can you try that?

Comment: [off-topic] Hmm, this code makes 2 requests every second. [/off-topic]

Comment: @josephnvu -  I tried trim but it has no affect.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko - is it bad practice to have 2 requests?

Comment: i am surprised that `result` isn't null each time, because you return it before the `success` function is called. You should the compare/replace inside of of the `success` callback

Comment: Well, yes since you already have data on the client. And what will happen if network lags for a few seconds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You code actually has some drawbacks.

1. You are making sync request which is a bad practice and even deprecated in main UI thread.
2. You are making requests twice.
3. You are using `setInterval` what if network lags for a few seconds?
4. You are accessing the DOM to check if data was actually changed.

Consider the following fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/Pxe2V/

```
var prev; //store previous data here
function update() {
    $.get('/currentshow.php').done(function(data) {
        if(data !== prev) { //if data was changed perform DOM manip.
            $('#current-show').html(prev = data);    
        }
    }).always(function() { //Launch next request when prev is done.
        setTimeout(update, 1000);    
    });            
}

update();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should do your comparison inside the `success` callback. Make sure that current show does in fact return the innert HTML and not the `"#current-show"` element

```
 var auto_refresh = setInterval(
    function (){

      var result = null;
      jQuery.ajax({
         url: '/currentshow.php',
         type: 'get',
         dataType: 'html',
         async: false,
         success: function(data) {
             result = data;
             cs = jQuery('#current-show').html();
             if (cs != result) {
               jQuery('#current-show').html(result);
             }
         } 
      });

  }, 1000);
```